# When Div is visible by changing css , the event on that div will occur several times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hidden

```
$('nav .show_all').on('click', function() {
    $('#all_pages').
    addClass('active').
    css('opacity', 0).
    animate({
        opacity: 1
    }, 1000);
    Book.all_pages();
    return false;
});



 all_pages: function() { 
 alert ('test1'); // test here is ok
 $('#slider li').click(function() {
 alert ('test2'); // this test is not ok
 });
 }
```

The above is the sample when the user click on nav.showall, it open an div #allpage. The bug here is when user close the div and open it again , the number of function runs is affect by the number of div close .

For example, when the user open the div box for the first time, it will alert one time 'test' , if the user open the div box , close it , and open again, it will alert two time 'test' and so on. How to fix this?

Comment: can you simulate the problem in http://jsfiddle.net ? thank you

Comment: Your snippet looks ok, the issue must be somewhere else.

Comment: any AJAX in page that is reloading this same code again? Same handler called again will fire as many times as it is called

Comment: Are you adding the click event multiple times via some other event?

Comment: Sorry. I went to lunch, the function has not fired several time, but all the events inside it has eg. the click event in this case.

Comment: I fixed the problem with using unbind whenever the box is close (hide)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign a **global variable** in Javascript and increase it counter while clicking on the object so you can track according to requirement here is dummy data here:

```
var i=0;
function your_function(){
     ///.......
     // your code goes here
     if (i % 2 == 0) {
         alert('You Open it :)');
     }
     i++;
}
```

Comment: You could just add an alert and see if it pops up twice. It would be easier. Plus I believe that the `$` in your if statement should not be there.